# How to display Camera Stream with Xamarin.Forms. Is it possible?

Tags: c#, camera, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So I have created an interface and implemented this interface currently in my Windows Phone 8 application to start a camera stream. Like so:

```
public void StartCamera()
{
      var cam = new Microsoft.Devices.PhotoCamera(Microsoft.Devices.CameraType.Primary);
      System.Windows.Controls.Canvas canvas = new System.Windows.Controls.Canvas();
      var videobrush = new System.Windows.Media.VideoBrush();
      canvas.Background = videobrush;
      videobrush.SetSource(cam);
}
```

so now the `canvas` object is holding a camera stream. But how Do I then pass this back to Xamarin forms and display it.

In Xamarin Forms I have:

```
IOperations camera = DependencyService.Get<IOperations>();
if (camera != null)
{
    camera.StartCamera();
}
```

and this works apart from obviously I have no control to display the camera stream. How would I display this stream in Xamarin forms?

Comment: Look into custom renderers, you would make your own CameraCanvas and the renderer code will attach the video brush to it. Idk about iOS and Android tho

Comment: I was afraid you were going to say custom renderer. I'll look into it, thanks for the point in the right direction

Comment: I would advise people to look at Xamarin Forms Labs as they have a camera and photo picker call [https://github.com/XForms/Xamarin-Forms-Labs](https://github.com/XForms/Xamarin-Forms-Labs)

Comment: Did anyone come any closer to this? I've been trying to get AVCaptureSession to work in my iOS target (of my Xamarin.Forms project). I want to get the raw images from the video feed (the stream).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is now a new Custom Renderer example project available here:

http://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/CustomRenderers/ContentPage/

With a walkthrough of this sample available here:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/contentpage/

I know this is a link only answer but due to the complexity of the question it would be too time consuming to repost the links contents

There is also now a control by the Xamarin Community toolkit called CameraView

[Xamarin Community Toolkit Camera View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/cameraview)